# Como ocultar o mostrar Imagenes en un DataGridView c#?

Tags: c#

Tengo una columna de imágenes con `DataGridview` pero al momento de dar clic a una `row` quiero quitar la imagen y sustituirla por otra.

**¿Alguien me puede ayudar?**

Comment: qué has intentado?

Comment: agrego la imagen de esta manera:
object imagen = @"C:\Sistemas DVA\Sistemas Satelites\FestinSucursal\Resources\checkboxVacio.png";
tablaMesas.Rows.Add(imagen);

Comment: esa parte si me ha funcionado el momento es que cuando quiero utilizar el evento CellClick no obtengo la imagen para poder remplazarla por otra

Comment: puedes anexar el código a tu pregunta? así es más fácil ayudarte :D